# Show errors on Field on load form

Tags: react-final-form

I use react-final-form with material-ui and put defaultValue from database which sometimes can be wrong (they where push in the database by a script). Is there a way to display errors, when the component loads ?

```js
<Field
  component={MyComponent}
  defaultValue="my value from database"
  name="name"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't share much code, so I'm not 100% sure what you're attempting to do, but...

If the field has an error, it will be present on first load.

Rather than `defaultValue`, you should be setting the `initialValues` in the `<Form/>` component with the values from the database.

Hope that helps?